# Java ConcurrentModificationException at java.util.Abstractlist

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code in Servlet class, I am getting

```
ConcurrentModificationException checkforcomodification at java.util.Abstractlist
```

at  `for (Projects persist: projectList) {`

How can I fix this and what causes this exception

**Code snippet**

```
List<Projects> projectList = new ArrayList<Projects>();
Projects project = new Projects();
projectList.add(project);
for (Projects persist: projectList) { // error in this line
persist.setPNo(pNo);
persist.setExpirtyDate(eDate;

myDAO.persistProjects(projectList);
projectList.clear();        
    }
```

Comment: Publish the whole for loop as you are probably adding or removing elements from the list and that's what causes the CME

Comment: @frisco I have included my full loop code by editing my answer, I am adding records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is you are clearing the list inside the loop `projectList.clear();`.

The last line in the for loop is throwing the error not the first line.

Probably you what you can do is to clear the list after processing the loop

```
List<Projects> projectList = new ArrayList<Projects>();
Projects project = new Projects();
projectList.add(project);
for (Projects persist: projectList) { // error in this line
    persist.setPNo(pNo);
    persist.setExpirtyDate(eDate);

}
myDAO.persistProjects(projectList);
projectList.clear();
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need

```
myDAO.persistProjects(projectList);
projectList.clear();
```

to be inside the loop?
You can not modify the list while iterating it.
Do the modifications and then after the loop clear and/or persist the list

Probably your code must be:

```
List<Projects> projectList = new ArrayList<Projects>();
Projects project = new Projects();
projectList.add(project);
for (Projects persist: projectList) {
  persist.setPNo(pNo);
  persist.setExpirtyDate(eDate;
}
myDAO.persistProjects(projectList);
```

`projectList.clear();` should not be needed unless you are reusing the list for other purpouses, but if needed always use it out of the loop.

The rule of thumb is just never modify the list you are iterating, you can circumvent that with iterators but usually it is not needed and adds a lot of boilerplate code, if you need to delete some objects it is usually better to create another list with the elements to delete and just delete the whole list after the loop, it is a lot more readable and avoids any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Move `projectList.clear();` outside of **`for`** loop.

Check out the API details of [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) for more details why this is an issue.

> if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over
>   the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will thow this
>   exception.

Answer (score 1):

While iterating if the structure of list is modified through another itarator or from a another thread, it will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You are removing all the elements while iterating the `List` which ensure **fail-fast** behavior of an iterator and throws `ConcurrentModificationException` as the list structure has been modified.